# ¿Cómo pongo "source" alternativos en CSS?

Tags: css, imagen, fuentes, src

Digamos que tengo un elemento `div` vacío con `id="icon"`:

```
<div id="icon"></div>
```

Y con CSS le añado tamaño e imagen de fondo:

```
#icon {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #808080;
    background-image: url("https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190617/original/pngtree-menu-vector-icon-png-image_3876237.jpg");
}
```

Y le pongo el `src` de otra imagen por si el primero ya no funciona:

```
#icon {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #808080;
    background-image: url("https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190617/original/pngtree-menu-vector-icon-png-image_3876237.jpg"),
    /* SRC extra */
    url("https://tmnwtools-1634481568309.web.app/icons/menu.webp");
}
```

Pero cuando veo la página, ambas imágenes se cargan una sobre la otra y se solapan en vez de usar una y usar la otra cuando la primera ya no funcione, y tengo mi página implementada así, causando un enorme consumo de datos. Algo similar me pasa con las fuentes:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Acherus;
    src: url("https://tmnwtools-1634481568309.web.app/fonts/acherus.woff") format("woff"),
        url("tmnwtools-1634481568309.web.app/fonts/acherus.ttf") format("truetype"),
        url("assets/fonts/acherus.woff") format("woff"),
        url("assets/fonts/acherus.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}
```

Se solapan una con la otra en vez de usar una cuando la otra no está disponible.

¿Alguien sabe de alguna manera de poner un "`src` alternativo" en CSS?
Gracias y espero que me puedas ayudar.

Comment: Claro, es el comportamiento esperado, no hay un mecanismo de fallback asociado, simplemente cargará todos los recursos que pases en las `url`.

Comment: Lo del "src alternativo" es solo para las fuentes, no para las imagenes de fondo, pues se muestran todas siempre (entiendo que lo hacen para superponer imagenes con fondos transparentes y darles algun tipo de efecto).  En cambio, en las fuentes si que son fuentes alternativas, pero tengo mis dudas si realmente se cargan todas a la vez o solo cuando no se encuentra la primera va a por la segunda, etc. Eso mirando la consola con el inspector de tu navegador lo puedes descubrir por ti mismo supongo.

Answer (score 0):

Felices fiestas **!**

Con respecto a la carga de imágen de respaldo, hay una solución muy simple en HTML que es muy eficiente: el atributo `onerror=""` en la etiqueta `img`. Éste evento de JavaScript se ejecuta cuando surge un problema en la carga de imágenes, documentos o multimedias:

```
<img src="miIMG.jpg" onerror="URLimagen"/>
```

Cuando `src=""` no se carga, entonces `onerror=""` sí carga.

Éste ejemplo sería lo más fácil:

```html
 
<h1>Imágen externo</h1>
<img src="miIMG.jpg" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='https://placeimg.com/200/300/animals';" style="width:100%">
```

Comment: Aunque el uso del atributo onerror es correcto el OP se refiere a la carga de imagenes desde css, no desde html o js, en css no existe forma de verificar si una imagen cargo o no

Comment: Por eso compartí una solución mediante HTML y JavaScript

Comment: El problema es que por cuestiones de seguridad no puedo usar JavaScript inline (onclick, onerror, onload, etc.), ya que mi página está protegida por Content-Security-Policy.